# Flask-Sqlalchemy: Select full row + derived "hybrid" model attribute

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my model I have a "hybrid method" for getting derived attributes,

```
class PersonT(Base):

        #...

        @hybrid_method
        def firstName_lastName(self):
            return func.upper(func.concat( self.get_first_name(self), ' ', self.get_last_name(self)))
```

I need to concisely fetch a full `PersonT` row **with this derived attribute**. By default it doesn't come back if I do this:

```
p = db_session.query(PersonT).filter(PersonT.id == id).first()
```

The derived attribute would only come back if I were to spell out the specific columns I want,

```
p = (db_session.query(
        PersonT.id, 
        #... list out all the columns ...
        NedPersonT.firstName_lastName.label('firstName_lastName'),
```

I want to quickly select the full row using the concise (first) syntax, without listing out specific columns, because I have hundreds of them, and then add this derived attribute as well. Is there a way to append it to the concise `query(PersonT)`?